# How to check if a program is ready for new input?

Tags: automation, autoit

I have a modeling program that I am automating some processes for using autoit. Part of this involves changing some display options. I need some way of determining when the program is done making the display updates and is ready for new inputs (to be clicked on and work). For example when the program is running a calculation I can use a do until loop using WinActive because while it is calculating it is considered inactive. However, after it is done calculating, there is a varying amount of time that the program takes to display the results and during this time the program is considered active but cannot accept new inputs successfully. I am currently using a sleep() command but would like to trim the fat so to speak by checking pragmatically instead of having wasted time waiting for a set, often unnecessary amount of time.

Comment: Using Autoit - the easiest way is to automate the manual way. So, what are you doing to get the info? Having that, try to use functions to check the info.

Comment: If you want help with refactoring its best to post code, just a side note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way. While the program is active but still thinking or updating the display and it is not yet ready for new input the mouse has a different symbol. By using Autoit's [MouseGetCurser()](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseGetCursor.htm) function to see if the program is ready or not. For my program, while the program was still updating the display, the curser value was 15 which means I can repeatedly pole the cursor value until the program is ready for the next input.

```
  WinWaitClose("Map Layers")
  Do
     sleep(200)
  Until MouseGetCursor() <> 15
```

Answer (score 0):

what ever language you are programming with you should implement Observer design pattern.

it will notify all classes of changes, so you wont need a pulling of data, each couple of seconds.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiQdrH2YpT4

Comment: AutoIt is for GUI Automation. So you can interact with a different program which is running unmodified. So your solution won't work, because you normally won't have access to the automated programs source code.